# Better way to generate JSON for a chatbot script

Tags: json, yaml, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot based website. I am using YAML to create the JSON files for the script for the chatbot.

The YAML files sort of look like this:

```
- Primer:
Conversation:
- Information2:
      label:
         head: Logistic Linear Regression
         ribbon: Equation Breaking 
         header: The gentle introduction to mayhem
      src: introduction
- Chat:
   messages: ['Hi {{user}}', 'Glad to see you here.']
- Information2:
      label:
         ribbon: Equation Breaking 
      src: history

Meta: {avatar: happy}
Reply:
  - Button:
     content: Hello Primer. Nice to meet you too. 
     label: Hello
  - Button:
     content: Hi Primer. It is a real pleasure seeing you too. 
     label: Hi there!
```

This is one basic unit of chat, where the bot ask questions, provides some information and the user selects option using Reply.

Writing this script in YAML is a pain because there is always some indentation error whenever I write content. I was planning to write a Racket based DSL for this usage, but didn't get any success in it (short timeline).

Can anyone suggest any better way to produce the JSON where I could write freely, knowing the script will compile to the JSON I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to use something like [RiveScript](https://www.rivescript.com/) which is expressive, commonly used and has a pretty wide set of tooling available for it.